# Htaccess в wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

Вот что есть в .htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

В корне с файлами wordpress я создал еще одну папку (pdf) и положил туда файл index.html и несколько архивов для скачивания, но при переходе туда выдается ошибка. Как разрешить доступ к этой папке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Положить в эту папку свой .htaccess, в котором:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```