# Как разрешить доступ к произвольной папке в директории WORDPRESS?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить такую задачу.

Есть корневая директория WP:

- wp-admin
- wp-content
- wp-includes
  ...

Я создаю в этой директории папку static со своим статическим сайтом:

- wp-admin
- wp-content
- wp-includes
- static
  --- css
  --- images
  --- index.php
  ...

Но когда захожу по этому адресу mysite.ru/static, то сервер выдает "Ошибка сервера 500".

Думал проблема в .htaccess (RewriteEngine). Попробовал загрузить файл в свою папку с опцией "RewriteEngine off" - не помогает. Также пробовал пустой .htaccess загрузить - тот же самый результат.

Совет из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/206695/htaccess-%D0%B2-wordpress) вопроса, к сожалению, не помог (только в моем случае **index.php**)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос содержимое .htaccess из корня сайта. И сервер у вас Apache?

Comment: Добавьте еще содержимое `static/index.php`, проблема и в нем может быть.

Comment: *сервер выдает "Ошибка сервера 500"* — смотрите в логах *http-сервера* — чем именно вызвана ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы. Проблему решил. 

У меня были неверные параметры подключения к базе данных в файле config.php, который инклюдился в index.php. Поэтому сервер отдавал ошибку.